# (closed) Postman can't be opened properly

Tags: postman, indexeddb

I'm trying to open my newly installed Postman when an error occurs which says something like this:

```
**Could not open Postman**
Error: Migration: IndexedDB schema migration failed. IndexedDb was not upgraded succesfully after `dexie.open`.
Please try restarting the app. If the issue persists, please refer to http://go.pstmn.io/troubleshoot-could-not-open
```

As it says, the error really persists. The website above only provides suggestions like "reinstall the app" "upgrade the app", which are not really helpful. And as I dig into the Internet, it occurs to me that such error hardly happens (found nobody have the same question like me).

"IndexedDb" was mentioned in the error message, and I just know (from the Internet) that it's a nosql database provided by explorer. Maybe the problem can be solved by reinstalling the database, I guess?

Comment: Are you able to post this as a question on the https://community.postman.com site please, we'll be able to figure this all out for you.

Comment: And mention your OS type and version.

Answer (score 7):

Use this: It worked for me.

```
pkill -fi Postman
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and found this description: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4897

Short answer is, **delete the Postman configs directory at** `~/.config/Postman` (for Linux) and then try running again.  This will delete any saved Postman data you have, but for a newly-installed instance that's not an issue.

Comment: Instead of deleting the whole Postman folder, just delete the IndexedDB folder in ~/.config/Postman. I got this error while performing an upgrade, and i cannot afford to remove the whole Postman Data

Comment: I faced a different error when starting postman.

`The disableGPU setting is set to undefined
Not disabling GPU
`
I also solved it by deleting `~/.config/Postman`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try just by deleting the “Postman” folder or renaming it to “Postman.old” from below two locations and then reinstall the latest version from here and see if that helps?

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming`

I tried it as I was facing the same issue and, it solved for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to installation folder of `Postman`:

```
C:\Users\Davoud\AppData\Local\Postman
```

delete the older version's folder. It fixed my problem. Actually I also deleted `update.exe` too.

[image]

Comment: This works for me after delete version `app-10.7.0` and using windows 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 - in my case, I have to:

- Open *Task Manager* and kill/end the Postman application.
- Go to `%appdata%` and search the "Postman" folder.
- Inside "Postman" folder, select the "Postman_Config" folder<sup>1</sup>. Delete it.
- Try to open your Postman instance again.

---

<sup>1</sup> The "Postman_Config" folder contained (*in my case*) another folder called "0" and inside this folder, an "userconfigs.json" file - which only contained these characters:

```
{}
```

If you have additional information,please, make a copy of these files in order to have a backup - if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows -
Kill the process that says, **postman** from the task manager
Run the installer again, it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**disable hardware acceleration** in the Postman menu in macOS, or the Help menu in Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing Postman when I was on a VPN (on Windows).  It started up but then got a popup error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined," and a blank white screen afterwards.  So I uninstalled it, deleted any Postman folders, turned off the VPN, and re-installed it with no problems!  After it installed successfully, I was able to turn on my VPN and had no further issues.

For reference, I had these errors in my `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Postman\logs\renderer-requester.log` file

```
[20076][1645655031650][requester][info]["Migrations: Committing IndexedDB upgrade"]
[20076][1645655031665][requester][error]["Could not complete migration.",{"name":"Error","message":"Migration: IndexedDB schema migration failed. IndexedDb was not upgraded successfully after `dexie.open`.","stack":"Error: Migration: IndexedDB schema migration failed. IndexedDb was not upgraded successfully after `dexie.open`.\n    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:477:1448541\n    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:3000934\n    at Ve (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2996146)\n    at ze (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2996903)\n    at IDBOpenDBRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2997272)"},{"0000_initial":"started","0001_add_archived_resources_table":"started","0002_add_variable_sessions_table":"started","0003_add_editor_tables":"started"}]
[20076][1645655031673][requester][error]["Migration: Could not complete migration.",{"name":"Error","message":"Migration: IndexedDB schema migration failed. IndexedDb was not upgraded successfully after `dexie.open`.","stack":"Error: Migration: IndexedDB schema migration failed. IndexedDb was not upgraded successfully after `dexie.open`.\n    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:477:1448541\n    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:3000934\n    at Ve (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2996146)\n    at ze (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2996903)\n    at IDBOpenDBRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:2:2997272)"},{"0000_initial":"started","0001_add_archived_resources_table":"started","0002_add_variable_sessions_table":"started","0003_add_editor_tables":"started"}]
[20076][1645655031676][requester][info]["booted - requester"]
[20076][1645655031686][requester][error]["Could not complete migration.",{"name":"TypeError","message":"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined\n    at t.default (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Postman/app-9.13.0/resources/app.asar/js/scratchpad/scratchpad.js:477:1193039)\n    at 
......
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve Postman's longer loading issue follow the below steps:

1. Uninstall postman.
2. Delete the Postman folder from the below directories:

   -> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local
   -> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\
3. Reinstall the postman.
4. It will be asked to log in, and login into the web.
5. All done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently, do following simple **step** it'll **fix your issue**.

1. **End Process** from Task Manager.
2. **Download** the latest version from: [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/).
3. **Install** and **retry** opening Postman it'll work smooth without any issues.
4. **Reference**: [GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4897)